# How do I limit access to a report folder to certain users only?

Tags: reporting, reports-folder, custom-permission

I need to have a report folder that is accessible to management only, but can't seem to figure it out. We have many folders for various sections of the business, and all users have access to public folders because of this. The management folder should only be viewable by given permissions.

I don't want to remove access to public folders from my profiles, because that will mean going into every other folder to grant access. It's just this one folder that needs restriction to one group.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: if it is the data that is sensitive, the consider different sharing rules rather than trying to restrict access to a specific report folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'd have to remove the Manage Public Folders permission, because this permission automatically gives access to all folders created by users. There's no way to hide a public folder from a user with Manage Public Folders, so if you really want to do this, you're going to have to do it the hard way.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I wish there was a folder 'type' one could select :). Thanks